# Find reverse of string using recursive

Tags: python

I am writing recursive function, but it is not working. Here is my code,

```
def reverse(s):
    if not s:
        return ' '
    return reverse(s[1]) + s[0]
```

Comment: What problems are you encountering? Do you get an error with a descriptive message? What *in words* do you think your function should do? How would you code each part of that? Why do you do `reverse(s[1])`? What do you *expect* it to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tweak little logic as,

```
def reverse(s):
    if not s:
        return ''
    return reverse(s[1:]) + s[0]
```